# iOS - Writing Core Data Unit Tests in Swift

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, testing, core-data

Recently I have been trying to convert the majority of my code in a project to swift.  Things were going fairly smoothly until I hit a number of unit tests that tested the applications Core Data functionalities.  Here is the test in question, I have a number of questions regarding issues that I have encountered while trying to run it.

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
import CoreData

class CalculateConversationSinceTimeTest: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testCalculateSinceTime() {
        let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()])!

        let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
        persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSInMemoryStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: nil, options: nil, error: nil)

        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

        let calculateConversationSinceTime = CalculateConversationSinceTime(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, messageRetentionPeriod: 9000000, bareJidStr: "test")
    }
}
```

This unit test tests a swift class called `CalculateConversationSinceTime` (not a view controller), and as it stands all it does is creates an instance of the class.  My first question is regarding the setup of the `managedObjectModel`, `persistentStoreCoordinator` and the `managedObjectContext`.  I have never done this in a swift unit test and would like some validation that its being done correctly.  Secondly, I am seeing a number errors/warnings inside the `testCalculateSinceTime()` and can't seem to figure out why.  First off I get an error that says that `CalculateConversationSinceTime` does not have a member named init when I try to initialize a new instance.  The initializer is correctly defined inside the class and I am able to use it in other areas of the code that aren't unit tests.  Why am I getting this error?  The second issue arises when I try to call a public method defined inside the `CalculateConversationSinceTime` class.  Swift keeps telling me that the instance I created of `CalculateConversationSinceTime` is of type `<<error type>>`.  Why is my instance not initializing properly?  Could someone please provide some insight into why I am seeing these problems? Thanks.

Comment: The app is a different Swift module. I do not see you importing that module. So how can your test case code know about it? You need to import the app module, and you need to make `public` everything in it that the test case needs to see.

Comment: In the `CalculateConversationSinceTime` class under "Target Membership" I select the project and the project tests targets.  Is this not enough? Do I also need to import the Swift module? @matt

Comment: hahaha wow! Ah either way importing the module doesn't help me, in fact it creates another error inside the unit test as it says that the module does not exist.  But thanks for the help! @matt

Comment: Then the problem is that you do not know the correct name of your app target as a module. You need to figure out what it is.

Comment: What I would advise you to do is to forget all about this project for a moment. Make a whole new project from the Single View Application template. It gives you a test target and an app target. Write a test that refers to a class defined in the app. You will see what you have to do in order for that to compile. When you've done that, you will understand how to do it in your real project.

Comment: Ah that will also tell me if its an issue with my current project or something unrelated.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am a huge fan of this technique: try to reproduce the problem in the smallest possible clean project. You can learn a lot that way!